# Python List Filtering Removes Too Many

Tags: python-3.x, list, filtering

I python list of urls as strings. I'm trying to remove all strings that have two forward slashes in them (//). Here is how I am attempting to do it:

```
filtered_list = [x for x in original_list if 'https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player//' not in x]
```

However, when I run this, it removes all strings with // and additional strings that don't even include //.

Here is a sample of the original list:

```
original_list = ['https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player/devonta-smith/123433',
'https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player//0',
'https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player//116922',
'https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player/alex-leatherwood/123411']
```

What can I change so it only removes string with // in it?

Comment: can you replicate the strings that should be removed and are not? when tesing your code all seems to be OK.

Comment: Hi @CarlKristensen I edited the question to include a sample of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working.
But another way to do this could be via regex.

```
import re

original_list = ['https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player/devonta-smith/123433',
'https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player//0',
'https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player//116922',
'https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player/alex-leatherwood/123411']

filtered_list = [x for x in original_list if not re.match(r"^https://.*//", x)]
filtered_list
```

filter_list:

```
['https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player/devonta-smith/123433',
 'https://www.ourlads.com/ncaa-football-depth-charts/player/alex-leatherwood/123411']
```

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why it's not working on my machine, but the regex version works!